# How to read switches via serial port C++?

Tags: arduino, serial-port, arduino-c++

I have an arduino nano. I want to connect MX Cherry switches and detect pressing throught the serial port. What pins should i use on arduino and what code should be uploaded to the plate?

I understand that i have to power the switches so there has to be 5v pin and input pin. But i'm new to electronics so i didn't manage to figure it out.

```
//that's just basic code for sending a number every second via 13 pin
int i=0;
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(57600);
  pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
}
void loop() {
  i = i + 1;
  Serial.println(i);
  delay(1000);
}
```

Basically, i need a way of sending '1' if button is pressed and '0' if it's not.

Comment: What do you mean by plate? What communication protocol does the switch you have use? Can you add specifics? Maybe add links to the data sheets of the switches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps I've misunderstood your question.  Why not just read the button and send a '1' if pressed and '0' if not?

```
void loop(){
  int buttonState = digitalRead(buttonPin);

  // Assumes active low button
  if (buttonState == LOW){
     Serial.print('1');
  } 
  else {
     Serial.print('0');
  }
  delay(500);
}
```

Of course you probably want to add some sort of timing to that so it doesn't send thousands of 0's and 1's per second.  I added a delay, but that might not be the best answer for the application you have (and chose not to share).  I've also assumed that your button is wired active-LOW with a pull-up since you didn't share that either.